# Sharepoint 2007: How to use default ID as value in a field?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have a fully customized SharePoint form by Infopath, I'm using a customized button to perform the submission.

I need to make the file name(or Name column) to be `'AAA1', 'AAA2', 'AAA3'` and so on. I have a field that displaying the file name in the form as well.

In the button, I added one rule:

1. Submit data using data connection.
2. Rename the field to `'AAA' + @ID`.

But I can't get the `@ID` from the available fields. I only can see those fields that I added in the form, but not the default columns like `Name, Title, ID`.

How can I use those columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID in SharePoint list will be available after item is saved to the list. Anyway there are a few solutions in this case. You can change your rule in this way:
1. Query the list with new data connection - Get ID's in DESC order from the list 
2. Select ID - it will be last ID value in this case 
3. Add 1 to last ID.
4. Set field name.
Regards